# Sentry: event_from_exception() to HTML

Tags: python, logs

I have a Python dictionary returned by the sentry method `event_from_exception()`.

I would like to format it as nice HTML.

But I guess this was already invented before.

Required features:

- open source
- implemented in Python

Example how to create the event data structure:

```
import sys
import json

from sentry_sdk.utils import event_from_exception

try:
    raise ValueError()
except Exception as exc:
    event, info = event_from_exception(sys.exc_info(), with_locals=True)
    print(json.dumps(event, indent=2))
```

A general purpose pretty printing of json is a first step, but something like this is way better: [image: traceback-in-django-debug-view]

Here is an example how to json looks like:

```
{
  "exception": {
    "values": [
      {
        "stacktrace": {
          "frames": [
            {
              "function": "<module>", 
              "abs_path": "/home/foo/tmp/t.py", 
              "pre_context": [
                "import json", 
                "", 
                "from sentry_sdk.utils import event_from_exception", 
                "", 
                "try:"
              ], 
              "lineno": 7, 
              "vars": {
                "exc": "ValueError()", 
                "__builtins__": "<module '__builtin__' (built-in)>", 
                "event_from_exception": "<function event_from_exception at 0x7f620a1d0578>", 
                "__file__": "'tmp/t.py'", 
                "__package__": "None", 
                "sys": "<module 'sys' (built-in)>", 
                "json": "<module 'json' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.pyc'>", 
                "__name__": "'__main__'", 
                "__doc__": "None"
              }, 
              "context_line": "    raise ValueError()", 
              "post_context": [
                "except Exception as exc:", 
                "    event, info = event_from_exception(sys.exc_info(), with_locals=True)", 
                "    print(json.dumps(event, indent=2))", 
                ""
              ], 
              "module": "__main__", 
              "filename": "t.py"
            }
          ]
        }, 
        "type": "ValueError", 
        "value": "", 
        "module": "exceptions", 
        "mechanism": null
      }
    ]
  }, 
  "level": "error"
}
```

Comment: Possibly related, but no way a match, an old, well received, question of mine : [The grand, unified theory of PHP error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247248/the-grand-unified-theory-of-php-error-handling)

Comment: @Mawg AFAIK sentry has a client/sdk for PHP too. In my case I would like to avoid the server. All that I am currently missing is a nice HTML which gets created from the sentry data structure.

Comment: Can you post an example of such a structure?

Comment: @Mawg I updated the question. It contains a sample json now.

Comment: Thanks. I think that will give you abetter chance of getting a dedicated answer.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that what you want is specific to `sentry_sdk`.

You just want a generic function to "`pretty print`" a Python dictionary, to HTML.

It is easy enough to code for yourself (and fun with recursion ;-), but others have already invented that particular wheel.

See, for instance:

- this [python dictionary object to html5 json form generator](https://github.com/mehmetkose/dict2form)
- the blog entry [Pretty printing a Python dictionary to HTML](https://www.stevetrefethen.com/?p=28)
- and [this S.O question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41671436/how-convert-python-dictionary-to-html-table) which says that you can do it with [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/), and shows how this code:

  import pandas as pd

  a = {'Job1': {'2017-01-10': [44, 33, 11, 75, 22]},
  'Job2': {'2017-01-05': [25, 25, 0, 100, 25],
  '2017-01-10': [50, 50, 0, 100, 25]},
  'Job3': {'2017-01-03': [44, 22, 22, 50, 22],
  '2017-01-04': [66, 36, 30, 54, 22],
  '2017-01-06': [88, 52, 36, 59, 22],
  '2017-01-10': [132, 68, 64, 51, 22],
  '2017-01-02': [22, 9, 13, 40, 22],
  '2017-01-08': [110, 52, 58, 47, 22]},
  'Job4': {'2017-01-10': [25, 25, 0, 100, 25]}}

  df = pd.DataFrame(data=a)
  df = df.fillna(' ').T
  df

generates this HTML table:
[image]

I wanted to take the JSON from your example and run it through each of these, but you did not post it and I cannot generate, as I don't have `sentry_sdk`.

As I said, I think you want a generic solution, not something specific to `sentry_sdk`. If you agree, change the title of your question to something like "Generate HTML Table from Python dictionary", as which point, I am sure that @SteveBarnes and others will make more suggestions, possibly better than these.

Comment: Yes, pretty printing is a first step. You are right. I updated my question.

Comment: But didn't change the title :-)  Ok, now it seems that you are not so worried about JSON as you are about stack trace (unless the trace is given in JSON; do you have an example?). Again, this is nothing that is specific to that SDK and if you ask a generic question you are much more likely to get an answer.

Comment: yes, I did not change the title. What title do you think would fit?

Comment: I am looking for a way to display this particular structure.

Comment: Yes, but it is highly unlikely that anyone has written code dedicated to that particular structure. If they have, it also unlikely here that anyone here ever heard of it; you would probably get a better response on a forum dedicated to that SDK than here.  I still think that your data (which you don't show (raw JSON, please?)) and nothing special and that a generic solution will handle them. And generic solutions are much easier to find than tailor made specifics, plus they can be reused in many places in the future.

Comment: I am deeply relaxed. I am not in a hurry. I don't search for an easy to find solution. I search for a a solution which makes me smile.

Comment: Lol. And your comment makes me smile :-) I wish you every success in your serach

Answer (score 1):

Since I could not find a solution, I wrote one myself: https://github.com/guettli/sentry-event-to-html

It is a simple python library which takes the json created by the sentry client and creates HTML.

Comment: Please accept your own answer, to show other who read this that it worlks. Of course,you asked on the wrong site; coding questions belong on https://stackoverflow.com/ I ca see from your profile that you knwo that now, so this remarks is just for others

Comment: No, wait, don't accept your won answer, because your GitHub says "`State

Unfinished`". Why did you even ell us about it? That helps no one

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica you say this helps no one. My unfinished project is a first step. You are allowed to improve it. The first step might help people who are able to solve the second step.

Comment: Agreed + upvote. Apologies. My initial thought was that this is not an answer, but you are correct, we can fork it. Just out of curiosity - 1) will you work on it more? 2) is it/can it be generic? Nothing to do with JSON/Sentinel, just a generic exception handler?

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica I won't have time for this during the next months. Feel free to clone it. Or I could even move over the owner ship to you.